# Writing to an xml file

Tags: c#, xml

i was wondering if i am adopting the correct approach to write to an xml file because when i view the file after this the changes are not present

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("pubs.xml");

    XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;

    XmlElement pub = doc.CreateElement("Pub");
    XmlElement name = doc.CreateElement("Name");
    XmlElement address = doc.CreateElement("Address");
    XmlElement postCode = doc.CreateElement("PostCode");
    XmlElement score = doc.CreateElement("PubScore");

    name.InnerText = txtName.Text;
    address.InnerText = txtAddress.Text;
    postCode.InnerText = txtPc.Text;
    score.InnerText = txtPs.Text;

    pub.AppendChild(name);
    pub.AppendChild(address);
    pub.AppendChild(postCode);
    pub.AppendChild(score);

    root.AppendChild(pub);

    doc.Save("pubs.xml");
```

This, in the root of the document should write an element like

```
<Pub>
    <Name>xxx</Name>
    <Address>xxx</Address>
    <OnlineRating>xxx</OnlineRating>
    <PostCode>xxx</PostCode>
</Pub>
```

**attempted change :**

```
   private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        XDocument doc = new XDocument(
            new XElement("Pub",
                new XElement("Name", txtName.Text),
                new XElement("Addresss", txtAddress.Text),
                new XElement("OnlineRating", txtPs.Text),
                new XElement("PostCode", txtPc.Text),
            )

        );

        doc.Save("pubs.xml");
    }
```

Comment: try using XmlSerilizer, it'll be a lot simpler to read and write xml failes once use learn it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using .NET 3.5 or above, then you could write that as:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
   new XElement("Pub",
       new XElement("Name", "xxx"),
       new XElement("Addresss", "xxx"),
       new XElement("OnlineRating", "xxx"),
       new XElement("PostCode", "xxx")
   )
);

doc.Save("pubs.xml");
```

And you're done!

Similarly, if you want the XML as:

```
<Pub>
    <Name FirstName="Xyz" SecondName="Abc" />
    <PostCode Code="8787"/>
</Pub>
```

Then you can do this instead:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
   new XElement("Pub",
       new XElement("Name", new XAttribute("FirstName", "Xyz"), new XAttribute("SecondName", "Abc")),
       new XElement("PostCode", new XAttribute("Code", "8787"))
   )
);

doc.Save("pubs.xml");
```

---

If you want to load an existing XML file, and you want to append these to that file, then do this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("pubs.xml"); //load the existing file!

//add one element with its descendants
doc.Add(new XElement("Pub",
           new XElement("Name", "xxx"),
           new XElement("Addresss", "xxx"),
           new XElement("OnlineRating", "xxx"),
           new XElement("PostCode", "xxx")
         )
     );

doc.Save("pubs.xml"); //save the whole document!
```

Comment: when i paste that in to visual studio it seems to complain about compile errors - seems like its the line breaks and spaces causing the issue?

Comment: I think it is missing a comma after the "Pub"

Comment: @simon: Now it should compile. Try!

Comment: that fixed most of it, now it just says argument missing on the first closing )

Comment: @simon: Post the code. I think, your code is not exactly same as mine

Comment: @simon: Alright, there was one extra-coma after `XElement(),` <<-- like this!

Comment: ahhh ok i see :) thanks, it still isnt working. I dont understand how it can know to save and edit the document when we arent loading it in the first place?

Comment: @simon: It will create a document with that name. It will not load anything from exiting file. And I didn't understand what you mean by *still not working*?

Comment: ahhh ok, where will that save then - i am trying to append the nodes to an existing file

Comment: @simon I'm confused. How is it possible that the code snippet in the questions does not change the file and this does? Nawaz's syntax is much nicer, but how did it actually solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

May be completely wrong but have you tried changing:

```
 pub.AppendChild(name); 
 pub.AppendChild(address); 
 pub.AppendChild(postCode); 
 pub.AppendChild(score); 

 root.AppendChild(pub);
```

to

```
root.AppendChild(pub); 

pub.AppendChild(name); 
pub.AppendChild(address); 
pub.AppendChild(postCode); 
pub.AppendChild(score);
```

Just because that makes more logical sense to me...

Comment: You sure you're not getting any exceptions about not having permission to access the file or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Just executing your code snipped on "pubs.xml" that looks like this...

```
<SomeElement>
    <SomeTag1/>
    <SomeTag2/>
    <SomeTag3/>
</SomeElement>
```

...produces the following "pubs.xml"...

```
<SomeElement>
  <SomeTag1 />
  <SomeTag2 />
  <SomeTag3 />
  <Pub>
    <Name>name</Name>
    <Address>address</Address>
    <PostCode>post_code</PostCode>
    <PubScore>score</PubScore>
  </Pub>
</SomeElement>
```

...which, if I understand you correctly, is what you want (you said: *"..**in** the root of the document should write an element like..."*).

So whatever is causing your problem is outside the code snipped you have shown us.

Are you sure the `doc.Save("pubs.xml")` is succeeding and not throwing an exception (e.g. due read-only flag)?

Also, are you sure you are viewing the **right** "pubs.xml"? Perhaps you have more than one copy and you happen to look at the wrong one? Look at `doc.BaseURI` to confirm the actual location of the file being written to.